# SwiftUI Setting a State on init

Tags: swiftui, state

If i don't have an initial value for a `@State` and set it in the `init` I get a Fatal Error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS, but only in Release Mode

```swift
public struct TestSetStateView: View {
  @State var item:Int
  public init(item: Int) {
    self.item = item
  }
  public var body: some View {
    Text("Hello: \(item)")
  }
}
```

If i add a default value

```
public struct TestSetStateView: View {
  @State var item:Int = 0
  public init(item: Int) {
    self.item = item
  }
  public var body: some View {
    Text("Hello: \(item)")
  }
}
```

and call it with `TestSetStateView(item: 8)` it shows "Hello: 0"

If I move that to `onAppear`

```
public struct TestSetStateView: View {
  @State var item:Int = 0
  let firstItem: Int
  public init(item: Int) {
    firstItem = item
  }
  public var body: some View {
    Text("Hello: \(item)")
      .onAppear(perform: {
        item = firstItem
      })
  }
}
```

and call it with `TestSetStateView(item: 8)` it shows "Hello: 8" which is great

or if i use the `_` wrapper:

```
public struct TestSetStateView: View {
  @State var item:Int
  public init(item: Int) {
    _item = State(initialValue: item)
  }
  public var body: some View {
    Text("Hello: \(item)")
  }
}
```

and call it with `TestSetStateView(item: 8)` it shows "Hello: 8", which is also great!

I'm just not sure what's happening, why can i use `item = firstItem` in `onAppear` and not in `init`. I sort of understand that the `_` uses the `@State` wrapper but why don't we have to use the in `onAppear.` Also not sure why the error in the first example only happens in release.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How could I initialize the @State variable in the init function in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58758370/how-could-i-initialize-the-state-variable-in-the-init-function-in-swiftui)

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
public struct TestSetStateView: View {
  @State var item:Int
  public init(item: Int) {
    _item = State(initialValue: item)
  }
  public var body: some View {
    Text("Hello: \(item)")
  }
}
```

is correct. Until a `State` variable is initialized, you can't set the underlying value directly. Remember, `State` is a property wrapper. The type of `@State var item` is not `Int`, it is a `State` that happens to contain an `Int`. It could just as easily contain a `Double` or a `String`. Trying to set a `State` with a value of `Int` makes as much sense as setting a `String` with an `Int`. You have a type mismatch. Frankly, the compiler should have screamed that you can't do that, but instead you get a crash.

Once the `State` var is initialized, it knows how to handle changing its underlying wrapped value directly. You can also initialize it directly elsewhere. Even the code: `_item` refers to the wrapped value, and not the state itself. Why they chose different semantics in the `State` property wrapper initializer, I don't know. But they did, and excluded us from using the convenience `init()` of the `@State` declaration in our view inits.