# Passing a state variable to parent view

Tags: swift, swiftui, view, state

I have the following code:

```
struct BookView: View {
    
    @State var title = ""
    @State var author = ""

    var body: some View {
        TextField("Title", text: $title)
        TextField("Author", text: $author)
    }
}
```

```
struct MainView: View {
    @State private var presentNewBook: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            // ... some button that toggles presentNewBook
        }.sheet(isPresented: $presentNewBook) {
        let view = BookView()
        view.toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: principal) {
                TextField("Title", text: view.$title)
            }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

This compiles but is giving me the following error on runtime:

```
Accessing State's value outside of being installed on a View. This will result in a constant Binding of the initial value and will not update.
```

How do I pass a state variable to some other outside view? I can't use `ObservableObject` on `BookView` since that would require me to change it from `struct` to `class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, your state should always be owned higher up the view hierarchy. Trying to access the child state from a parent is an anti-pattern.

One option is to use `@Binding`s to pass the values down to child views:

```
struct BookView: View {
    
    @Binding var title : String
    @Binding var author : String
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Title", text: $title)
        TextField("Author", text: $author)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var presentNewBook: Bool = false
    
    @State private var title = ""
    @State private var author = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Title: \(title)")
                Text("Author: \(author)")
                Button("Open") {
                    presentNewBook = true
                }
            }
        }.sheet(isPresented: $presentNewBook) {
            BookView(title: $title, author: $author)
        }
    }
}
```

Another possibility is using an `ObservableObject`:

```
class BookState : ObservableObject {
    @Published var title = ""
    @Published var author = ""
}

struct BookView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var bookState : BookState
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("Title", text: $bookState.title)
        TextField("Author", text: $bookState.author)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var presentNewBook: Bool = false
    @StateObject private var bookState = BookState()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                Text("Title: \(bookState.title)")
                Text("Author: \(bookState.author)")
                Button("Open") {
                    presentNewBook = true
                }
            }
        }.sheet(isPresented: $presentNewBook) {
            BookView(bookState: bookState)
        }
    }
}
```

I've altered your example views a bit because to me the structure was unclear, but the concept of owning the state at the parent level is the important element.

Comment: @dsynkd You had added a comment yesterday about what you're trying to achieve, but now it's removed. Is there something else I can add here that will clarify things enough for you to accept the answer?

Comment: @jpndx Sorry about that! I removed the comment because I thought it might've been a stupid question. Your answer is good, and I upvoted it, but it's not quite what I was looking for. I do not want to use ObservableObject, because I have to create a state class, and I wanted to try to avoid the added complexity. And I did not want to use Binding, since that would mean repeating all of the variables as State in the class I am passing the binding to. I went with what I posted below. What do you think about that?

Comment: Your answer doesn't compile with the code that you've given in your question. It fails with "'$title' is inaccessible due to 'private' protection level". It seems like an anti-pattern in SwiftUI to me.

Comment: Thanks for that, I fixed the answer. I am essentially trying to initialize an 'edit view' by passing in the object to be edited into the view. I wanted to use the State wrapper to have the reactive view properties. The only other alternative I can think of is using an Environment Object, something like currentBook, which is set before the edit view is initialized. But I am not sure if that would be better. What would you suggest in this case would be the correct pattern in SwiftUI?

Comment: Using a Binding would be, by far, the most common way to achieve this.

Comment: I see. So, if I understand currently, the use case for Binding would be to pass in a State object, which is exactly my original question. I have now accepted your answer. But, Bindings would still fall short (I might be wrong on this) if say, the variable I am passing is not a State in the parent view (say, generated by a ForEach), but needs to become State in the detail view. In that case, would my approach below be the correct way for this?

Comment: Hasty comment. I believe passing a variable into a struct that uses State automatically converts the passed variable into a State variable.

Comment: I don't know of any automatic conversation of something to a State variable, but perhaps I just need to see the example to understand. In terms of coming from a ForEach, you can use the "element binding syntax". Here's a good primer on that and Bindings in general: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/bindable-swiftui-list-elements/

Answer (score 0):

You can also pass a state variable among views as such:

```
let view = BookView(title: "foobar")
view.toolbar {
     ToolbarItem(placement: principal) {
         TextField("Title", text: view.$title)
     }
}
```

Then, inside of `BookView`:

```
@State var title: String

init(title: String) {
    _title = State(initialValue: title)
}
```

Source: [How could I initialize the @State variable in the init function in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58758370/how-could-i-initialize-the-state-variable-in-the-init-function-in-swiftui)