# State Variable From A Textfield With Input Is Returning Null

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a custom struct which contains a Textfield, and a state variable associated with the textfield. Every time I just try to validate the Textfield, the state variable is null, even if there is input inside the Textfield. Is there some thing that I am missing?

This is in my Signup class:

```
//
//  Signup.swift
//  Lazuli Social
//
//  Created by user207789 on 12/28/21.
//

import SwiftUI

struct Signup: View
{
       
    //If Everything Is Valid
    @State var isValid: Bool = false;

    init()
    {
        
       
    }
    
    
    var body: some View
    {
        NavigationView
        {
            GeometryReader
            {
                metrics in
            
                VStack (alignment: .center)
                {
      
                   //First Name
                    var first:EnhancedTextField = 
                    EnhancedTextField(hintIn:"First name", widthIn: 
                    metrics.size.width, 
                    heightIn:metrics.size.height,typeIn:0);
                                     
                    //Displays First
                    first;
                    
                    Button(
                            action:
                            {  
                                
                                if(first.checkErrors()==true)//THE INPUT IS BLANK HERE, EVEN WITH INPUT TEXT
                                {
                                    //There Was Some Error
                                    isValid=false;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    //No Error
                                    isValid=true;
                                }
                            }
                            ,label:
                                    {    
                                       
                                     Text("")
                                       
                                    })
                    //Next Button
                    NavigationLink(destination: AccountInfo(),isActive: 
                    .constant(isValid==true))
                    {
    
                   
                    }
                    .navigationBarHidden(true)
                    .navigationBarTitle("")
                    .disabled(isValid==false)
                }
            }
            
    }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .navigationBarTitle("")}
}
```

Here is my custom struct, which contains the Textfield:

```
//
//  EnhancedTextField.swift
//  Lazuli Social
//
//  Created by user207789 on 12/29/21.
//

import SwiftUI


     
    
struct EnhancedTextField: View
{
    @State var hint: String;
    
    //First Name Input
    @State public var text: String = "" //THIS IS NULL, EVEN WHEN THERE IS INPUT
    
    //If First Name Focus Is Changed
    @FocusState public var isFocused: Bool
    

    //StringDetector Class
    var detector: StringDetector
    
    
    public func checkErrors() -> Bool
    {
        if(type==0)
        {
            let result = checkErrorsFirstName();
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    public func checkErrorsFirstName() -> Bool
    {
        //StrignDetector Result
       let result = detector.checkErrorsFirstName(first:self.text);//THIS IS WHERE I'M TRYING TO PASS THE INPUT OF TEXTFIELD TO AN INTERNAL CLASS FOR STRING VALIDATION, HOWEVER IT IS ALWAYS EMPTYM EVEN WITH INPUT
           
           //Error Text
           errorText=result.1;
           
           //Bordrer Color
           borderColor=result.2;
           
           //Icon String
           iconName=result.3;
           
           //Icon Color
           iconColor=result.4;
        
        //There Is An Validation Error
        if(result.0==true)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
        
            
    }
    
   
    var body: some View
    {
        
            VStack (alignment: .center)
            {
                
               //First Name Input
               TextField(hint, text: $text)
              .padding(.bottom, height*Alpha.tAlpha)
              .padding(.top, height*Alpha.tAlpha)
              .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
              .focused($isFocused)
              .textInputAutocapitalization(.never)
              .disableAutocorrection(true)
              .onChange(of:isFocused)
              {
                  newValue in
                  
                  if (newValue==false)
                  {
                      //Check Validation Errors
                      checkErrors();
                      
                  }
                  .padding(.horizontal, width*0.10)
              
                      
                }
               

        }
    
}
```

Thanks,

Isaiah Thompson

Comment: Your "Signup class" looks a little confusing and looks like it violates some principals of SwiftUI. For example, it doesn't look like `EnhancedTextField` ever gets added to the view. Also, calling a method *on* a reference to a view is basically never something you want to do. In general, state should be held in a parent view, validation checks should be done on view models, etc.

Comment: If you include a [mre], it'll be easier to give more concrete suggestions.

Comment: I have reduced the code, in my EnhancedTextField class for clarity. I have a Bachelor's Degree in Computer Science, however, I'm trying to port over an app written in Java. It seems like SwiftUI, is less object-oriented and more procedural

Comment: It's good to have lesson code to test in `EnhancedTextField`, but the code that I'm more concerned about is your "Signup class" where it looks like you're trying to test these conditions -- that's what seems to violate the SwiftUI principals. You're correct that SwiftUI is not an object-oriented framework -- it's a declarative layout framework, which can be a big mind-shift coming from imperative programming (which seems like what you're trying to do in that signup class)

Comment: Thanks, Jnpdx. I have added a more full version of my Signup class

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still not a [mre] -- there's too much missing. See what happens if you try to paste it into a blank project. But, now that I see more of `Signup` (which isn't a class, it's a struct), I see that my suspicions were correct. You should not be trying to hold references to views and reach into child view's state and call methods on them. State should be owned by a parent view and passed down via bindings if necessary -- [here's an example of that type of scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69545247/passing-a-state-variable-to-parent-view).

Comment: Sorry, it it definitely a Struct. I'm just used to Object-Oriented programming. In my days using C, a Struct is basically like a collection of variables contained within a data structure. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: `structs` in Swift are very similar, but there's a really important distinction between `struct` and `class` which is that `struct`s are passed by value and `classes` are passed by reference -- that'll turn out to be a very relevant concept as you learn more Swift and SwiftUI. Another hint: `@State` should basically *never* be `public` (in fact, it would be great if there were a lint rule to warn people about this)

Comment: That is definitely something to keep in mind for sure. Thank you again Jnpdx, for all of your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a *very* simplified version of your code showing state owned by the parent. Validity just tests whether the text is empty or not (just for demo purposes).

```
func checkErrors(input: String) -> Bool {
    return !input.isEmpty
}

struct Signup: View
{
    @State private var text : String = ""
    @State private var isValid : Bool = false
    
    var body: some View
    {
     
        EnhancedTextField(hint: "Hint", text: $text)
            .border(isValid ? .clear : .red)
            
        Button(action: {
            isValid = checkErrors(input: text)
        }) {
            Text("Test")
        }
    }
}

struct EnhancedTextField: View
{
    @State var hint: String
    @Binding var text: String
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool
    @State private var hasErrors = false
    
    var body: some View
    {
        
            VStack (alignment: .center)
            {
                
               //First Name Input
               TextField(hint, text: $text)
              .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
              .focused($isFocused)
              .textInputAutocapitalization(.never)
              .disableAutocorrection(true)
              .onChange(of:isFocused)
              { newValue in
                  if !newValue
                  {
                      //Check Validation Errors
                      hasErrors = checkErrors(input: text)
                  }
                }
        }
    }
}
```